# Changing a path for logger using Form application and implementing it to Service with C#

Tags: c#, winforms, service

I am working on a File Watcher service which has a form application in it too (2 different projects in same solution). So I am getting a path for where to save the log with Forms application. Then I put that in my `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="location" value="C:\Users\user\Documents" />
        <add key="logLocation" value="C:\Users\user\Documents" /> <!-- this is where it changes save it-->
    </appSettings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

And I have a `Variables` class where I define my variable.

```
using System.Configuration;

namespace FileWatchingService
{
    public static class Variables
    {
        public static string FilePath { get; set; } = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("location");
        public static string LogPath { get; set; } = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("logLocation");
    }
}
```

Then I am trying put my LogPath in here:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace FileWatchingService
{
    public static class Logger
    {
        public static void Log(string message)
        {
            try
            {
                string _message = String.Format("{0} {1}", message, Environment.NewLine);
                //File.AppendAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "logFile.log", _message);
                File.AppendAllText(Variables.LogPath + "logFile.log", _message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Implement logging on next version
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that my way does not work. What can I do to change my log files path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking solely at the code, it seems you're missing a `\` at the end of the **LogPath** value.
You could also do `File.AppendAllText(Variables.LogPath + "\logFile.log", _message);` or just define the LogPath itself, such as:

```xml
 <appSettings>
    <add key="location" value="C:\Users\user\Documents" />
    <add key="logLocation" value="C:\Users\user\Documents\log.txt" /> <!-- the file itself -->
  </appSettings>
```

Nevertheless, I would advise to just use a library for logging, instead of developing your own. Go with [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/) or [Serilog](https://serilog.net/)